# Why is this C++ string length calculation function faster than this other one?

Tags: c++, performance, function, pointers, string-length

Our lecturer has explained that this piece of function which calculates the length of a character string...

```
int strlen_1(const char *str) {
    const char *temp = str;
    while(*temp != '\0') {
        temp++;
    }
    return temp - str;
}
```

... will calculate it faster than this one...

```
int strlen_03(const char *str) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *(str+i) != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
```

I think he said that it was related to arithmetic calculations, something like in the first one any arithmetic calculus is done, but I cannot understand that, I see them both in the same level. Could you please explain me the reason in other words?

PS. I do understand pointers and I can understand what is going on, it is like stepping through the elements of the array stored into the "RAM cells" by one unit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PS: Micro-optimization is a bad idea. If you have performance problems first find out where it is using the most CPU

Comment: Turn on optimization and look at the generated assembly to get a clear picture of how they differ.

Comment: To the extent that your teacher is correct it's because the second one does two additions whereas the first only does one. However, as chris and Ed Heal have mentioned, it's generally pointless to worry about this level of hand-optimization until you've profiled the code and discovered an actual performance problem. And the assembly generated in optimized code could very well be identical anyway.

Comment: As an aside, while this question might be reasonably relevant to C, in C++ a simple `your_string.length()` will usually be substantially faster than either of the above since it's O(1) instead of O(N).

Comment: Thank you all very much guys. But regarding what @ooga said I don't really understand. In the first one we have the incrementation part of temp (which involves adding), and then subtracting the previous address from the incremented one (which involves subtraction): we have two calculations. In the second one we have the str+i part which is one operation and the incrementation as well, which are 2 in total as well. So why does the first one just involve 1 operation?

Comment: What's important is what's inside the loop (including the test and update portions in the for and while). There are two additions in the second loop but only one in the first loop.

Comment: I finally got it now, thanks for having patience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the optimization for a moment and just looking at the paper algorithms:

The former performs this calculation repeatedly:

```
addr++
```

with a result calculated by a difference calculation

```
addr1 - addr0
```

the latter performs these calculations repeated

```
addr0 + i
i++
```

with the result being calculated by a value-return

```
i
```

In other words, twice as much work is being done *in* the loop for the benefit of doing half as much in calculating the final result.

getting to the optimized ASM, the first generates this at -O3 on my clang:

```
0x100000ee4:  cmpb   $0, 1(%rbx)
0x100000ee8:  leaq   1(%rbx), %rbx
0x100000eec:  sete   %al
0x100000eef:  testb  $1, %al
0x100000ef1:  je     0x100000ee4
```

the second generates this:

```
0x100000f09:  incl   %ebx
0x100000f0b:  cmpb   $0, (%rax)
0x100000f0e:  leaq   1(%rax), %rax
0x100000f12:  sete   %cl
0x100000f15:  testb  $1, %cl
0x100000f18:  je     0x100000f09
```

I left out the constant one-timers for the return values because they are not core to the complexity of the loop. The optimizer is pretty good, noting the only major difference is that single:

```
0x100000f09:  incl   %ebx
```

which is your `i`

Comment: And CPU parallelism probably means that the `incl %ebx` doesn't actually involve any delay.

Comment: Nice point. So it is more theoretically rather than practical. Maybe if we had a very very limited piece of hardware it would be interesting. But you say it does not involve any delay?

Answer (score 5):

This is a micro-optimization, and a modern compiler would likely end up generating the same assembly for both, but for a non-optimized version, here is why:

```
int strlen_1(const char *str) 
{
    const char *temp = str; // declare the iterator
    while(*temp != '\0')   // dereference the pointer
                           // test the iterator 
    {
        temp++; // increment the iterator
    }
    return temp - str; // pointer subtraction
}
```

For a string of length N, this gives you 3N + 2 operations.

```
int strlen_03(const char *str) 
{
    int i; // declare your iterator
    for (i = 0; *(str+i) != '\0'; i++); // initialize the iterator
                                        // add i to str
                                        // dereference that pointer value
                                        // test it against \0
                                        // increment i
    return i;
}
```

For the same string, this gives you 4N + 2 operations.

Again, a modern compiler will likely fix this for you, and this small loop isn't likely to make much of a difference even in the un-optimized form for most strings (only for *very* long strings).

Comment: Thanks Zac, it is a very clear answer. I think I got it finally. By the way what is the meaning of 3N or 4N? And what are the +2? Pardon me for my ignorance.

Comment: @RamonBlanquer It means the number of pseudo-operations. the + you see is one-time operations. The first has a two one-timers (init and the subtraction-eval) + 3 ops per iteration (deref, test, inc). the second has two one-timers (init and i-eval) and 4 ops per iteration (add, deref, test, inc).  At least thats the way I was taught so many moons ago.